# Are C structs allocated on the heap if they contain a pointer?

Tags: c, struct, memory-management, heap-memory, allocation

In my program I have a method that instantiates a structure and returns it something like this

```
struct A {
    int a;
    double * dblPtr;
    double ** dblMatrix;
}


struct A initStruct(int a) {
   struct A instance;

   instance.a = a;
   instance.dblPtr = malloc(sizeof(double));
   instance.dblMatrix = malloc(sizeof(double *) * 5);

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      instance.dblMatrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(double));
   }

   return instance
}

int main() {
   struct A a = initStruct(1);
   doOtherStuff(a);
   doMoreStuff(a);
   return 0
}
```

Does this struct get heap allocated or stack allocated? In my program I continue to use the struct after its returned so I presume it isn't stack allocated because then it would get wiped when I exit the initStruct scope right?

So Is it heap allocated?
And why/how does that work?

Im expecting its heap allocated.

Comment: Memory returned by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` is allocated on the heap. Other memory is not. "In my program I continue to use the struct" You do not.`a` in `main` is not the same as `instance` in `initStruct`. In any case, "I do X and it appears to work/do what I want" is radically different from "X is the correct way to do things and it will still work tomorrow/in a different program/with a different set of compiler flags".

Comment: Your code does not compile and it does nothing, so how do you know that "it works"? But anyway there is nothing really wrong here, `initStruct` returns `instance` and in `main` `a` contains an exact copy of `instance`.

Comment: @Jabberwock its pseudo code but thank you thats kind of what I was looking for, I know that "It works" because when I pass the a variable to other functions and the function modify its members the change is persistent in a even outside the function scope.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI if I were to return a pointer to the struct from initStruct would that be more correct? Thats kind of what I suspect

Comment: The structure `instance` in `initStruct()` is a stack variable. As such, it does go out of scope when `initStruct()` returns. However, C allows the return of structures by value, so the entire `instance` structure returned to `main()` (also via the stack) and can be assigned to the variable `a`. ‘a’ then contains a copy the structure that existed as `instance` in `initStruct()`.

Comment: @willaayy No. In that case, the pointer returned to `main()` points to variable no longer in scope.

Comment: The code as you have it works because the stack variable `instance` gets copied on `return instance`. The alternative to this is to pass `initStruct` a pointer to the object it should initialize: `struct A a; initStruct(&a, 1);` and have it modify the object in-place. Unless you have a large struct or do this billions of times copying the struct is just fine.

Comment: @PaulLynch So If I want to instantiate a struct with a function and return the same struct and returning it like I do returns a exact copy and returning a pointer is wrong how should I do it.

Comment: @willaayy The way you’re doing it – returning an automatically-allocated (usually stack) struct – works, because structs can be returned by value (`main()` gets a copy). Or, you could dynamically allocate the struct (`struct A *instance = malloc(sizeof(instance));` and return it. But note `instance` must then be a pointer; `struct A initStruct(int a)` must be changed to `struct A *initStruct(int a)` and member access operators have to change (`->`). Or use @GoswinvonBrederlow’s method.

Comment: Oops. `struct A *instance = malloc(sizeof(*instance));`

Answer (score 4):

> Are C structs allocated on the heap if they contain a pointer?

No.

When you declare `SomeType SomeName;` inside a function, the program allocates space for an object of that type using automatically allocated storage (usually implemented with a stack), when program execution reaches that declaration. The type of `SomeType` is irrelevant.

Your `struct A` is a type that contains an `int`, a `double *`, and a `double **` (which is a bad way to implement a two-dimensional matrix). Ultimately, those are just bytes. When it is allocated on the stack, it is simply enough bytes for an `int`, a `double *`, and a `double **`, including whatever padding the compiler lays out for the structure. The fact some of those bytes will be used as pointers is irrelevant to allocating space for the structure.

Further, you should not associate pointers with dynamically allocated memory (often implemented with a heap). A pointer can point to an object in statically allocated memory, an object in automatically allocated memory, an object in dynamically allocated memory, or an object in thread memory (and function pointer types can point to functions).

> Does this struct get heap allocated or stack allocated?

When discussing C semantics, you should refer to these as dynamically allocated<sup>1</sup> and automatically allocated. They are often implemented using a heap and a stack, but there are exceptions, and their semantics in C are as specified in the C standard, not governed by the properties of heaps or stacks.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The C standard uses “allocated” as a name for the storage duration of dynamically allocated memory, but this is an unfortunate abridgment as the term is also used to refer to reserving memory of all storage durations.

Answer (score 0):

The struct is allocated on the stack, not on the heap.

I see that your main source of confusion is that the struct is used *outside* the scope it was first initialized, which can be concerning when you know that the stack unwind after leaving a function. *shouldn't the struct be lost* ?

It works because `return` promises that this data is available for the caller scope. In a way, you could consider that the original was lost but you kept a copy.

But your intuition is good, because the following would be an issue indeed

```
struct A *initStruct(int a) {
   struct A instance;

   instance.a = a;
   instance.dblPtr = malloc(sizeof(double));
   instance.dblMatrix = malloc(sizeof(double *) * 5);

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      instance.dblMatrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(double));
   }

   return &instance
}
```

Returning a pointer to a an object that was allocated in the callee is dangerous, because only the pointer will be secured for the caller, not the struct it points to !